# Microsoft Excel 2003 Limit Value between two Values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to get around writing a macro. I have a field with a function involving a small calculation. If the result is greater than 1, it should set the result to 1. If the result is smaller than 0, it should set the result to 0. Since I need a matrix for graph plotting I cannot use if statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function is in **A1**, use:

```
=MAX(MIN(A1,1),0)
```

*(you can also embed your function in place of the `A1` in the formula above.)*
*(no IF statements using in the approach)*